# How to check if 'debugger;' keyword exists?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes some developers forgot to remove `debugger;` in javascript code, and it produce javascript error on IE.
How can you check (like for the console: `if(window.console){console.log('foo');}`) if a debugger exists?

BTW: I don't want to detect if the browser is IE, I want a generic method if possible
Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot.

The best solution would be adding a hook to your version control system to prevent code containing `debugger;`  statements from being committed/pushed.

Asking your devs to search for `debugger;` or at least have a careful look at the diff before committing is also a solution - but not as effective as hard-rejecting in the VCS.

Comment: Not even with a `try ... catch` block?

Comment: No.. `debugger;` is meant to break into a debugger, not to be caught.

Answer (score 5):

You could attempt to compile a function that declares `debugger` as a local variable.  If `debugger` is reserved as a keyword, the JS engine will throw an error which you can catch.

```
var debuggerIsKeyword = false;
try {
    new Function("var debugger;");
} catch(e) {
    debuggerIsKeyword = true;
}
```

However I'm not sure that knowing whether a keyword exists or not is actually helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the safest approach is to have a global include file for all your projects that stubs out the debugger if it doesn't exist:

```
if (typeof debugger == 'undefined') {
    window.debugger = null;
}
```

That way calls to debugger just become a reference to null. which is harmless. Seems like a better approach than expecting forgetful developers to wrap each debugger call in an if statement.

The same approach works for console.log, etc.

EDIT: As AndrewF points out, debugger is actually a keyword, not a global, so this won't work. The same effect can be achieved using the following without throwing an error:

```
window['debugger'] = null;
```

Comment: `debugger` is a reserved word, and thus it "may not be used as variables, functions, methods, or object identifiers". This code ought to cause a parse error.

Answer (score -3):

Haven't tried it for lack of an IE, but this should work:

```
if (typeof console !== 'undefined') {
  console.log("logging enabled");    
}
```

Comment: Then use `if (typeof debugger !== 'undefined') {dowhatever();}`

Comment: this will never gonna work as debugger is a keyword and not a type... you would not expect 'typeof for' to produce anything meaningful do you?

Comment: if (typeof Debug !== 'undefined') {dowhatever();}