# Debugging jasmine 2.0 tests with resharper

Tags: javascript, resharper, jasmine

I want to debug a JavaScript Unit Test inside jasmine 2.0 within Resharper 8, i.e. I want the test to pause so I can open the Chrome debugger to look at variables etc. There is an stackoverflow answer for Jasmine 1.3 given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585883/debugging-jasmine-tests-with-resharper-and-phantom-js), but this does not work in jasmine 2.0.

Anyone got a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found one way to stop a Jasmine 2.0 Unit Test returning to Resharper. Whether its the best way I don't know, but it works. Include the line below in the test you don't want to complete.

```
ReSharperReporter.prototype.jasmineDone = function () { };
```

You will need to press stop on Resharper Unit Test page to stop the test.

I should say that doing this doesn't stop the Jasmine test finishing, so you don't have access to any locals inside the test. I have voted up [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-286219) on the Resharper web site as there has to be a better solution. If you have this problem then I suggest you vote this up too.

Comment: Jon - note that the R# issue you mention has now been closed as a duplicate for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-286219